# How to get default home application?

Tags: android, default, android-launcher

I want to get default home application name.For this i used

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        ResolveInfo resolveinfo =getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY); 
defaultHomeName = resolveinfo.activityInfo.name;
```

This returns **com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity**  and when I tried following

```
    List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks =((ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService("activity")).getRunningTasks(1);
    if (runningTasks != null && !runningTasks.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < runningTasks.size(); i++) {
            RunningTaskInfo runningtaskinfo = (RunningTaskInfo) runningTasks.get(i);

        }
    }
```

got  home name as **com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.Launcher** inside this when on the home screen .

Why the same application shows different names?How to get a unique name for default home application for all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the same application shows different names?

Because they are not the same application.

Specifically, `com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity` is the resolver activity, what we tend to refer to as the activity chooser, or simply "chooser" for short. That comes up for `resolveActivity()` because there are two or more activities that can handle your chosen `Intent`.

> How to get a unique name for default home application for all devices?

By using `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`, instead of `resolveActivity()`, you will get a list of all installed home screens. If this list has more than one entry on it, after filtering out your own home screen (should you be writing one), you have no reliable way necessarily of determining which of those is the "default home application".